# Can a Wizard gain more spell slots by having multiple spell books?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, equipment, spell-slots, spellcasting

Can a Wizard gain more spell slots by having multiple spell books?

If I had two or more spell books each with different spells, does that increase the spell limit?

Comment: Are you talking spell slots, spells prepared, or spells known? The question says "slots" but nothing about slots is related to the spellbook.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already and see the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 8):

The spellbook and the spells written in it make up the list of spells that a wizard can prepare during a long rest.

The number of spells that can be prepared is fixed by the wizard's class level, completely independent of the spellbooks.

Comment: While this is correct, the answer would be improved by citing/quoting the relevant rules.

Answer (score 8):

## No, spellbooks and spell slots are totally distinct.

All spellcasting classes in D&D have three separate traits that govern how they cast spells:

1. **Known spells**. This is the list of spells that they have learned how to cast. Knowing a spell doesn't mean the spell caster is ready to cast that spell at any given time. For that, there is ...
2. **Prepared spells**. This is the list of spells that they have available to cast in their minds, all of which must be from their list of known spells. Casting a spell doesn't remove it from this list; once a spell is prepared, it remains prepared until the spell caster changes their prepared spells. Usually prepared spells are changed after a long rest. But a caster can only cast a prepared spell if they can pay for it with magical energy, and this magical energy is measured in ...
3. **Spell slots**. A spell caster spends a spell slot of a level equal to or greater than the level of the spell they are casting. Spell slots are an inherent energy reserve in the spell caster that increases with experience level. Expended spell slots are generally recovered during a long rest.

For a [wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#ClassFeatures):

> Your spellbook is the repository of the wizard spells you know, except your cantrips, which are fixed in your mind.

So a wizard's known spells are exactly those spells written in their spellbooks.

> You prepare the list of wizard spells that are available for you to cast. To do so, choose a number of wizard spells from your spellbook equal to your Intelligence modifier + your wizard level (minimum of one spell). The spells must be of a level for which you have spell slots.
>
> You can change your list of prepared spells when you finish a long rest. Preparing a new list of wizard spells requires time spent studying your spellbook and memorizing the incantations and gestures you must make to cast the spell: at least 1 minute per spell level for each spell on your list.

So having more spellbooks doesn't change how many spells the wizard can prepare.

> The Wizard table shows how many spell slots you have to cast your wizard spells of 1st level and higher. To cast one of these spells, you must expend a slot of the spell’s level or higher. You regain all expended spell slots when you finish a long rest.

Spellbooks don't affect spell slots at all, so having more spellbooks doesn't allow a wizard to cast more spells without resting.

(Other classes manage the relationship between known and prepared spells differently; for example clerics know all cleric spells, but can only prepare a subset of them. Bards only know a few spells, but they always have all of their known spells prepared).